# Replacing one column onto another in python/pandas, but keeping the replaced columns values if the replacing column has a NaN value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in a data frame that I want to merge together. The attached image shows the columns:

[Image of the two columns I want to merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsOo4.jpg)

I want the "precio_uf_y" column to take precedent over the "precio_uf_x" column a new column, but if there is a NaN value in the "precio_uf_y" column I want the value in the "precio_uf_x" column to go to the new column. My ideal new merged column would look like this:

[Desired new column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIEWU.jpg)

I have tried  different merge functions, and taking min and max with numpy, but maybe there is a way to write a function with these parameters?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Don't post images, post text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.apply`.

```
def get_new_val(x):
    if np.isnan(x.precio_uf_y):
       return x.precio_uf_x
    else:
       return x.precio_uf_y

df["new_precio_uf"] = df.apply(get_new_val, axis=1)
```